# Re-add class after being detached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```js
jquery('input[name="checkout[pick_up_in_store][selected]"]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "true" && typeof code_happened === "undefined") {
        var addType = jquery(".additional-checkout-fields").html();
        jquery(".section--shipping-address .section__content").append(addType);
        window.code_happened = true;

        alert("Show Form!");
    } else if (this.value == "false" && typeof code_happened !== "undefined") {
        alert("Hide Form!");
        jquery(".fieldset.fieldset--address-type").detach();
        window.code_happened = undefined;
    }
});
```

The button is by default = false. When the button is selected and value is = true then the html displays with a form, when the button is selected again value = false and the html is hidden. However if you press the button again so the value = true then html doesn't display (due to the detach).

I'm trying to modify the above code so that the form shows when the value is set to true again.

Can you please advise?

Comment: The problem with using `detach()` when you want to insert it again is knowing where in the DOM it came from in order to put it back in the same place. Hide/show might be a better approach. You can also disable a fieldset and none of the controls within it will be submitted

Comment: @charlietfl    I should have specified that within the HTML is a form, that I want to disable not hide / show. So that isn't an option for me unfortunately. I'll update the question for this.

Comment: You could create a `var replacement = $('<span class="replacement>');` and then instead of detaching you could `$(selector).replaceWith(replacement);`.  Since the span is empty nothing will show.  Then later when you want the element back, `replacement.replaceWith(originalThing)`

Comment: OK but as I mentioned a `<fieldset>` can be disabled which effectively disables all the controls inside it. So wouldn't disabling and hiding it work the same?

Comment: @Taplar Was thinking of similar but would also need clone instead of detach doing it that way

Comment: @charlietfl    I tried getting this to work with clone, however couldn't get it to work - I was probably doing something wrong but unfortunately got stuck with it.

Comment: Just seems simpler to me to disable it. Why would that not work?

Comment: @charlietfl    with the code provided it re-adds the form every time, so it will hide but when it displays it adds another copy of the html.

Comment: Not clear how any duplication would occur from what is shown without a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl    each time the append runs it is adding the html again.

Comment: Really need to see a demo of this to help further. Using either of above approaches would affect all instances

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to hide the form use nother class like

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Instead of detaching the form fields just add the hidden class and remove it when (again) when the form is shown

```js
jquery('input[name="checkout[pick_up_in_store][selected]"]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "true" && typeof code_happened === "undefined") {
        var addType = jquery(".additional-checkout-fields").html();
        jquery(".section--shipping-address .section__content").append(addType);
        jquery(".fieldset.fieldset--address-type").removeClass('hidden');
        window.code_happened = true;

        alert("Show Form!");
    } else if (this.value == "false" && typeof code_happened !== "undefined") {
        alert("Hide Form!");
        jquery(".fieldset.fieldset--address-type").addClass('hidden');
        window.code_happened = undefined;
    }
});
```

Comment: - This works, however it re-adds the html every time, so duplicating it. It also doesn't disable the form within the html so values aren't stripped, but  retained.

Comment: "however it re-adds every time" - then remove the part that re-adds it and change to remove `.hidden` class.

Comment: @freedomn-m    If I wanted to make the form mandatory, then it wouldn't work if it was hidden. It would work better if the code was detached and then re-added.

Comment: @Revokez right, this solution says hide it (which you don't want), that's fine.  But you then say "it re-adds it" (without mentioning that you don't want to hide it).   So the solution is incomplete (hides/shows+adds) but I'm pointing out that your saying the *only* reason this doesn't do what you want is that it re-adds and, this solution, should be just (hide+show) and so I'm saying, if you wanted (hide+show) (which you didn't say to this answer that you didn't) then you should simply remove the (+adds) rather than pointlessly complain it doesn't do what you want because it re-adds.